# Creating a data frame by applying a function to each element of a vector and combining the results

Tags: r, purrr

I am working on a project where we frequently work with a list of usernames. We also have a function to take a username and return a dataframe with that user's data. E.g.

```
users = c("bob", "john", "michael")

get_data_for_user = function(user)
{
  data.frame(user=user, data=sample(10))
}
```

We often:

1. Iterate over each element of `users`
2. Call `get_data_for_user` to get their data
3. `rbind` the results into a single dataerame

I am currently doing this in a purely imperative way:

```
ret = get_data_for_user(users[1])
for (i in 2:length(users))
{
  ret = rbind(ret, get_data_for_user(users[i]))
}
```

This works, but my impression is that all the cool kids are now using libraries like `purrr` to do this in a single line. I am fairly new to `purrr`, and the closest I can see is using `map_df` to convert the vector of usernames to a vector of dataframes. I.e.

```
dfs = map_df(users, get_data_for_user)
```

That is, it seems like I would still be on the hook for writing a loop to do the `rbind`.

I'd like to clarify whether my solution (which works) is currently considered best practice in R / amongst users of the tidyverse.

Thanks.

Comment: From the answers I learned that my question contains an error. "...the closest I can see is using `map_df` to convert the vector of usernames to a vector of dataframes." is inaccurate. As the answers point out, `map_df` actually returns a single data frame (which contains an rbind of the results), not a vector of dataframes. `map_dfr` is a more explicit way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks right to me - `map_df` handles the `rbind` internally (you'll need {dplyr} in addition to {purrr}).

FWIW, `purrr::map_dfr()` will do the same thing, but the function name is a bit more explicit, noting that it will be binding rows; `purrr::map_dfc()` binds columns.

Comment: Oh wow - I totally misread the documentation for `map_df` - I thought that it was returning a vector of dataframes! I didn't realize that it also did an rbind for me!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slight adjustment:

```r
dfs = map_dfr(users, get_data_for_user)
```

`map_dfr()` explicitely states that you want to do a row bind. And I would be inclined to call this best practice when working with `purrr`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here are some additional approaches:

#### using built-in functions

```
Reduce(rbind, lapply(users, get_data_for_user))
```

#### using data.table approach

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(users, get_data_for_user))
```